# Add extra Fields to Django to Django Auth Groups

Tags: django

How add a new field in Group Model of the Django?
To use something like

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
g = Group.objects.get(pk=1)
g.extra_field = "something"
g.save()
```

it's posssible?

**EDIT:**

I need a persistent extra field.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't in the documentation but fine to use (pre to have a basic understanding of monkey patching), in your models.py or init add:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

Group.add_to_class('foo', bar)
```

Where bar can be any python object (or method), e.g.

```
def bar(self):
    return self.attr * 2
```

or using a field mapping:

```
Group.add_to_class('foo', models.RegexField(r'^hello$'))
```

Comment: Thanks Hedde. But a Need a persistent attribute. I'll edit the question!

Comment: It is persistent if you load it ahead. Do you perhaps mean a dbfield? Just assign models.CharField(stuff) as I said it can be any object..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I wanted to add an extra field in Groups. It worked for me - 
[Monkey patching](http://www.alrond.com/en/2008/may/03/monkey-patching-in-django/)